# Filter out services from prometheus node_exporter systemd

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I have a prometheus server stood up and a node_exporter running on one of my servers with the systemd collector enabled.  I am trying to limit/filter the services that are reported by the node_exporter.

I tried using node_exporter --collector.systemd.unit-whitelist and providing a regex to limit the services but I keep getting 
`WARN[0008] Couldn't create disabled collector: systemd   source="node_exporter.go:40"`

I am not sure what I am missing or if there is another way to limit the services that are reported back to just the specific ones I am interested in.  Has anyone tried this and been successful?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, somehow I missed the `=~` as being the series selector.  This got me to where I need to be.